# Android Studio: Button only one user can access at a time

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I'm currently working on a project with Android Studio where only one user should access a page at a time. So the button,where the page can be accesed, has to be disabled when the user clicks on it and has to be enabled when the user leaves the page. I'm programming with Java. Any ideas would be appreciated. My users are stored via Firebase.

Code you see below is executed when clicking the button

```
station1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, station_1.class);
startActivity(intent);
Toast.makeText(Home.this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});**strong text**
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding an object in firebase database to store the id of current user opened the page and the time user opened it( you should do a timeout mechanism so that a user don't block other users forever)

```
"page_lock" : {
"user_id" : "1000",
"open_time":"1646071356"
}
```

and when user open the page, you must check that difference between open time and current time is less than a minute, in such case don't open the page else open the page and update the page_lock.
Also in data change listener, you must check if user id is changed then force user to close the page, and in onDestroy reset page_lock or remove it from database.